# C# Do we need to close TCPClient by using TCPClient.Close if it is no more used?

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

I'm making a program which sends data to many TCP listeners. If one of the TCP Sending channel is no more used, do we need to close it using TCPClient.close. What happens if we leave it open?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wouldn't use `Close` explicitly - I'd just dispose it via a `using` statement:

```
using (TcpClient client = ...)
{
    // Use the client
}
```

> What happens if we leave it open?

If neither side closes the connection, it'll be sitting there doing nothing, pointlessly.

If the other end closes the connection, I suspect you'll have a local connection in TIME_WAIT or something similar for a while; I don't know the exact details but it's not ideal.

The main point is that it *may* use up some system resources, and fundamentally it's not ideal. Is it going to cause your program to crash and your system to go crazy? Probably not - at least unless you're creating a huge number of these. It's still a good idea to dispose of anything with non-memory resources though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Hmm..the 'using' statement.. I've never used that before though. Need to read on it. So, using 'close' is bad?

Comment: @user1034912: Close doesn't do a total cleanup of resources, but dispose does. The 'using' block calls Dispose() for you...

Comment: @user1034912: `Close()` isn't "bad" - it's just not as convenient as using `Dispose` via the `using` statement. You should be using a `using` statement any time you have something disposable which is created and then finished with in a local scope.

Comment: I've just read about using. Isn't 'using' limited to the curly brackets? i.e. the moment it leaves the curly brackets, the objects are disposed? My TCP client spans a larger segment of the code.

Comment: @user1034912: In that case you should probably make it a member of another class which *also* implements `IDisposable`, and write a `using` statement for that. It's fairly hard to give a detailed answer without knowing the details of what you're doing.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you leave it open, the GC (Garbage Collector) will in time dispose of your object.

With TCPClient, the finalizer (the code run when the GC cleans up your object) has a call to Dispose(), which in turn closes the connection and frees any OS resources used by it.

You don't know WHEN the GC does it's cleaning up, so this approach is undeterministic. This probably isn't a problem with one or two open connections, but you may starve the system of resources if you open a huge number of these.

A good practice would be to always dispose TCPClients when you're done with them, and this can easily be accomplished with the `using` block. (As shown in Jon Skeets answer...)